# Number of permutations with a prescribed constraint

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Consider the set $[n]:= \{1,\dots,n\}$. I am looking for the number of permutations $\sigma$ of $[n]$ such that $\sigma(1)$ belongs to fixed subset $S_1\subset [n]$. I have been stuck on this and am wondering if there is something simple that I am missing.

More generally, I would like to know the number of permutations such that $\sigma(i)\in S_i$ for fixed subsets $S_i$ with $i=1,\dots n$.

Answer (score 1):

The number of such would just be $|S_i|\cdot (n-1)!$.  This is clear since for each choice of $\sigma_i(i)$, there are $(n-1)!$ permutations $\sigma_i\in S_n$.

Comment: Thanks! This is clear for one set $S_1$. I guess I'm wondering more if there is more than one set, say $S_1,S_2$, then one has to take into account of where $\sigma(1)$ and $\sigma(2)$ go, if an inclusion/exclusion argument would work best..